# Combine data BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I'm quite new to firebase and bigQuery, but I'm collecting the data displayed below from Unity. And I would like to create a table out of this (cyclist 1 question 2 pre).

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_1' AND param.value.int_value = 1 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_relaxed_1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_2' AND param.value.int_value = 1 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_relaxed_2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_3' AND param.value.int_value = 1 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_relaxed_3,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_4' AND param.value.int_value = 1 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_relaxed_4,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_1' AND param.value.int_value = 2 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_investigative_1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_2' AND param.value.int_value = 2 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_investigative_2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_3' AND param.value.int_value = 2 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_investigative_3,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_4' AND param.value.int_value = 2 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_investigative_4,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_1' AND param.value.int_value = 3 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_confused_1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_2' AND param.value.int_value = 3 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_confused_2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_3' AND param.value.int_value = 3 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_confused_3,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_4' AND param.value.int_value = 3 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_confused_4,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_1' AND param.value.int_value = 4 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_fearful_1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_2' AND param.value.int_value = 4 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_fearful_2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_3' AND param.value.int_value = 4 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_fearful_3,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'cyclist1_question2_pre' AND param.key = 'mood_age_4' AND param.value.int_value = 4 THEN param.value.int_value END) AS C1_pre_fearful_4,
FROM `databaseName`,
UNNEST(event_params) AS param
```

Ideally the table looks like this.

| Relaxed | Investigative | Confused | Fearful |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mood_age_1 | mood_age_1 | mood_age_1 | mood_age_1 |
| mood_age_2 | mood_age_2 | mood_age_2 | mood_age_2 |
| mood_age_3 | mood_age_3 | mood_age_3 | mood_age_3 |
| mood_age_4 | mood_age_4 | mood_age_4 | mood_age_4 |

Anybody knows how to get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single event example:
[image]

The event_params is a key-value nested structure.

First step is to transpose the key to be an ordinary column.
This is done using the pivot table operation, for the sake of the example i will pivot the firebase_event_origin and firebase_screen_class keys.
The query that facilitate:

```
with T1 as(
select *
from (select event_date, event_timestamp, event_name, params.key as key,
            lower(coalesce(params.value.string_value,
                      cast(params.value.int_value as string),
                      cast(params.value.float_value as string),
                      cast(params.value.double_value as string))) as val,
from dataset.table_name, unnest(event_params) params)
pivot(max(val) for key in ('firebase_event_origin','firebase_screen_class'))
where event_timestamp=1647905194793001)
```

Results:

[image]

After the table was pivoted you can run a summary query similar to this:

```
select event_date,
countif(event_name='screen_view' and firebase_event_origin='auto') auto,
countif(event_name='screen_view' and firebase_screen_class='unitydefaultviewcontroller') unitydefaultviewcontroller
from T1
group by 1
```

Results:

[image]